# Running Count - Sum not summing when inputting less than expected quantity

Tags: excel, vba, sum, addition

I am using a form that takes an item and quantity. I'm trying to create a running count that consists of the quantity (denoted as `qtytxt1`, `qtytxt2`, etc) of each item. Each item has its own quantity input field denoted with the ending number (i.e., `qtytxt1` applies to item 1).

I am trying to have a cell located in `(emptyRow, 27)` to output the sum of the total quantity of all items inputted into the form (i.e., Item 1 qty = 2,000; Item 2 qty = 3,000; Expected Output = 5,000).

There are a total of 10 input fields for "Item/Qty," however, not all 10 fields are expected to be used. I have created a code that seems to work as I prefer, however, I would receive a **sum error**  message when entering less than 10 items.

```
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim runCount As Long
        
Worksheets("mining history").Activate
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("i:i")) + 6
Set data = Sheets("data")
runCount = 0

If qtytxt2.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt2.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt3.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt3.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt4.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt4.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt5.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt5.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt6.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt6.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt7.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt7.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt8.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt8.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt9.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt9.Value = 0
    
    ElseIf qtytxt10.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt10.Value = 0
    
End If

If IsEmpty(Range("E:E")) Then
    'Is Empty
    runCount = 0
    Else
    ' Not Empty
    runCount = WorksheetFunction.Sum(qtytxt1.Value, qtytxt2.Value, qtytxt3.Value, qtytxt4.Value, qtytxt5.Value, qtytxt6.Value, qtytxt7.Value, qtytxt8.Value)
        
    Cells(emptyRow, 27).Value = runCount
End If
```

Comment: Try `runCount = WorksheetFunction.Sum(CDbl(qtytxt1.Value), CDbl(qtytxt2.Value), ...so and so forth)` . It is better to convert the values to proper datatypes, especially when fetched from userforms. `CDBl` is a VBA function to convert to `Double`.

Comment: @Charlie Noted. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```vb
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim data As Worksheet, wsMH As Worksheet
Dim runCount As Long, n As Long, v

Set data = Sheets("data")
Set wsMH = Worksheets("mining history")
'no need to Activate...
emptyRow = wsMH.Cells(Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).row + 1

If Application.CountA(wsMH.Range("E:E")) = 0 Then
    runCount = 0
Else
    'loop all the entry textboxes
    For n = 1 To 10
        v = Me.Controls("qtytxt" & n).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then runCount = runCount + v
    Next n
    wsMH.Cells(emptyRow, 27).Value = runCount
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need this:

```
If qtytxt2.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt2.Value = 0
End If
If qtytxt3.Value = "" Then
    qtytxt3.Value = 0
End If
```

etc